# « À rien » ou « en rien » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

En parlant d'une commande informatique utilisée pour interrompre un processus, qui lorsque le processus ne dure pas plus de une seconde est complètement inutile du fait que c'est une commande manuelle (elle effectue cependant ce pour quoi elle est conçue pourvu que l'on ait le temps de s'en servir), on est confrontés à deux possibilités de formulation de cet état de chose. Apparemment, elles ne sont pas équivalentes. La question est de savoir si les deux peuvent être utilisées, même si, ce faisant, on distingue deux aspects légèrement différents du contexte, et quelle est la différence, ou de savoir, au cas où une seule est possible, de laquelle il s'agit et pourquoi.

Suivent ces deux possibilités :

- Elle arrête l'exécution, c'est à dire lorsque c'est possible, comme elle ne peut servir **à** rien pour stopper des instructions qui ne durent qu'une fraction de seconde.
- Elle arrête l'exécution, c'est à dire lorsque c'est possible, comme elle ne peut servir **en** rien pour stopper des instructions qui ne durent qu'une fraction de seconde.

Comment: Sur le fond, je dirais simplement que *la fonction arrête l'exécution d'un processus **en cours** d'exécution.* Le reste (qu'elle ne serve à rien à partir du moment où le processus est terminé découlant de source). Après, si tu veux vraiment préciser une évidence, sur la forme je dirais, de façon équivalente ***à** rien **pour** stopper* ou ***en** rien **à** stopper.*

Comment: @aCOSwt « en rien pour » ne serait donc pas tout à fait en accord avec le bon sens?

Comment: Si si. Pas de problème de (bon) sens. Pour ce qui est de la tournure je ne m'étais prononcé que sur la forme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour répondre à la question, *elle ne peut servir à rien* sous entend que la commande n'a pas d'utilité dans l'absolu (elle n'a pas d'effet); alors que *elle ne peut servir en rien* sous entend qu'elle a une utilité mais pas dans le cas présent. Je pense donc que la formulation la plus adaptée ici serait *en rien*.

Comme indiqué dans les commentaires la formulation est lourde, pour paraphraser tout en utilisant *en rien* pourquoi ne pas dire :

> Commande manuelle qui arrête une execution en cours, ce qui n'aide en rien pour des instructions qui ne durent qu'une fraction de seconde.

Comment: C'est la réponse que j'attendais un peu, elle confirme  ce que je présentait mais ne pouvait affirmer; je pense pouvoir utiliser « en » sans crainte maintenant. Pensez-vous que « Elle arrête l'exécution, c'est à dire lorsque c'est **humainement** possible, comme elle ne peut servir en rien pour stopper des instructions qui ne durent qu'une fraction de seconde. » conserverait toujours cet effet de lourdeur que vous semblez reconnaitre ou aurait-il s'agit plutôt d'un style pas assez dépouillé? Merci de vos opinions!

Comment: Le sujet fait penser à une documentation technique, auquel cas il faut éviter au maximum les formulations alambiqués, les phrases longues et les informations inutiles (ou induisant de la confusion). Dans cette optique je pense que "Elle arrête l'exécution d'une tâche en cours" est suffisant, à la limite vous pouvez ajouter "mais n'a pas d'effet autrement". Pourquoi vouloir préciser qu'elle n’arrêtera pas une tâche déjà terminée ?

Answer (score 1):

La formule habituelle est ***ne servir à rien***. Utiliser *en* n'est pas totalement impossible mais tout de même cent à deux cent fois moins courant.

---

<sub>Note hors-sujet: L'explication serait plus facilement compréhensible si elle était remaniée comme ceci :</sub>

> Cette commande interrompt un processus en cours d'exécution. Elle n'a autrement pas d'effet, c'est à dire si elle est exécutée avant que le processus soit lancé ou après qu'il se soit achevé par exemple parce qu'il ne durait qu'une fraction de seconde.

Comment: J'avais en tête d'exclure toute possibilité autre qu'une possibilité dont l'explication précèdait, par exemple celle par laquelle une utilisation *directement avant* l'exécution aurait permis de programmer un arrêt, par exemple encore, en fonction d'un temps d'exécution.  En ce qui concerne l'effet post-exécutoire (note hors-sujet) il me semble que l'on devrait alors parler d'annulation et non plus d'arrêt.

Comment: Sans savoir de quoi on parle, il est difficile de savoir s'il faut parler d'annulation ou d'arrêt. Je n'ai d'ailleurs utilisé ni l'un ni l'autre mais *interrompre* comme indiqué dans la question.